# Unable to install pandas to python3

Tags: python, python3, pip

Not able to install `pandas` and `python3-pip`.

Also tried these commands:

- `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`
- `sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools`
- `sudo python3 -m pip install pandas`

Comment: Just `sudo apt install python3-pandas`? No reason to pip.

Comment: yes it says `E: Unable to locate package python3-pandas`

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Comment: Hmmm, on a fresh install of 16.04 (VM), it works instantly.

Comment: `E: Unable to locate` means to run `sudo apt update`. If that doesn't fix it, then check your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems installing pandas](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070426/problems-installing-pandas) and [How do I enable the “Universe” repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/)