# Problems installing pandas

Tags: package-management, software-installation, python, dependencies

I am trying to install pandas on Ubuntu 14.04. I seem to have a problem with dependencies, but I haven't been able to install them. I am trying to install pandas via pip as follows:

```
vroni@zargedu4:~$ pip install pandas
```

And this is the error message:

```
SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.
```

If I try to install python-dev this happens:

```
vroni@zargedu4:~$ sudo apt-get install python-dev
python-dev :Depends: libpython-dev (= 2.7.5-5ubuntu3) but it is not installable
            Depends: python2.7-dev (>= 2.7.5-1~) but it is not installable
```

It basically misses these dependencies. Trying to install them only leads me to new messages like this.

```
vroni@zargedu4:~$ sudo apt-get install libpython-dev
libpython-dev : Depends: libpython2.7-dev (>= 2.7.5-1~) but it is not installable
```

and so on.

```
vroni@zargedu4:~$ sudo apt-get install libpython2.7-dev
libpython2.7-dev : Depends: libpython2.7-stdlib (= 2.7.6-8) but 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2 should be installed
                Depends: libpython2.7 (= 2.7.6-8) but 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2 should be installed
                Depends: libexpat1-dev but it is not installable
```

until I try..

```
vroni@zargedu4:~$ sudo apt-get install libpython2.7-stdlib=2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2
```

Then the answer is: it is already the newest version.

```
libpython2.7-stdlib is already the newest version.
```

I don't quite understand what's the problem here. I also tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install -f
```

and

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

and afterwards tried to install pandas again. but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. Usually these kind of problems happen after adding some alternative repository / PPA. Did you add any maybe conflicting repository? What is the output of `apt policy libpython2.7-dev` ?

Comment: Maybe it's the Python Package Index (PyPI). The Python Package Index (PyPI) is a repository of software for the Python programming language, commonly accessed by `pip install` and `sudo pip install` commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas is in the default repositories for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python-pandas  # for Python 2.x in Ubuntu 18.04 and earlier
```

or

```
sudo apt install python3-pandas # for Python 3.x
```

pandas is a Python package providing fast, flexible, and expressive data structures designed to make working with "relational" or "labeled" data both easy and intuitive. It aims to be the fundamental high-level building block for doing practical, real world data analysis in Python.

Comment: Thank you very much... such a simple solution... I feel very stupid right now :D!